# show/hide div jquery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am keeping having errors from the below code:

```
<input type="button" id="test" name="test" onclick="test();" value="Test"/>
function test(){
    $('#divUser').hide('fast');
    $('#divAddress').hide('fast');
    $('#divDetails').show();

}
```

or

```
        $('#test').click(function () {
            $('#Div3').show();
            $('#Div1').hide('fast');
            $('#Div2').hide('fast');
            return false;
        });
```

on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mohamad/rFhM6/

it is solved:
i replaced this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
 <script src="/jscripts/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Might want to wrap them in `<script>` tags to start with.

Comment: What are the errors? And could you show us the entire HTML code? I guess he have a <script> tag ot the code would not be interpreted as JS anyway.

Comment: *"I am keeping having errors from the below code"* What **kind** of errors? What's the error text? What have you tried? What do your tools say?

Comment: Try surrounding your second snippet of example-code with: `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems correct, except that your JavaScript function is not wrapped in a `<script>` tag (as pointed by ILMV in your comment):

```
<input type="button" id="test" name="test" onclick="test();" value="Test"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
    $('#divUser').hide('fast');
    $('#divAddress').hide('fast');
    $('#divDetails').show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: it is wrapped, but i didnt display it

Comment: As I said if it was not wrapped in <script> he will see the code instead of getting an error

Comment: You could even wrap both selectors in one function: $('#divUser,#divAddress').hide();